# Render Doc fails to launch my application

Tags: c++, debugging, vulkan, renderdoc

I have an executable file saved in the Debug folder of my Microsoft VS C++ project, the program runs fine when i double click on it and it basically shows me a 3D model that i can hover the camera around it, however when i try to run the program from render doc my console and SDL2 application window pops up and closes directly after that, all I am able to see is a Vulkan validation layer message as follows

```
validation Layer: While debugging through RenderDoc, debug output through validation layers is suppressed.
To show debug output look at the 'DebugOutputMute' capture option in RenderDoc's API, but be aware of false positives from the validation layers.
```

Iam using `RenderDoc v1.1` for debugging, `SDL2` for window and and event handling, `vulkan` as my graphics API and `C++`.
i cannot capture a single frame.

i have two debug folders one has the executable file while the other contains many dependent project files.

my main debug folder is as follows:-

[image]

note that i explicitly copied some dependent files and folder into this debug folder so that i would work directly by double clicking on the executable files

my debug sub folder is as follows:-

[image]

my renderDoc screenshot is as follows: -

[image]

Comment: Are you running it from the same path as VS does? Often VS does compile to e.g. a release sub folder but runs it in the parent folder, which is something you'd have to specify in RenderDoc via the working directory.

Comment: @SaschaWillems i have two debug folders, one has the executable file, the other has the dependent files, i copied some of the dependent files into the executable debug folder so that i am able to run it directly by double clicking on it, i also tried to change the render doc working directory to the debug folder with the dependent files but still it does not run, i put the screenshot of my folders and render doc into my post if you are interested

Comment: Then you may be using extensions not supported (and offered) by RenderDoc.

Comment: I had a similar problem. First, i downloaded the source code of RenderDoc from github and added the project into my VS solution. Then I ran RenderDoc from within VS so i could see where exactly it crashed. Since it didnt crash when I double clicked it, I added a `system("PAUSE")` at the start of my program, started it, opened RenderDoc with "Inject into process", then executed the PAUSE by pressing a button and then i could see where it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just like @Sascha Willems said, that's because I enabled VK_EXT_EXTENDED_DYNAMIC_STATE_3_EXTENSION_NAME device extension that RenderDoc not supported.